# wait(long timeout) in a while loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

I've read that you're supposed to put `Object.wait()` calls in Java in a while loop. The reason is that this thread may be woken up and the condition that you were waiting to notify on is still false (spurious wake-up).

What about `Object.wait(long timeout)`. Here, you don't want to loop on the condition since you want it to time out after the specified amount of time. But if you don't put it in a loop then how can you ensure that it won't be woken up early?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But if you don't put it in a loop then how can you ensure that it won't be woken up early?

This is a deficiency in Java IMO although maybe it's a deficiency with the underlying thread support in various OS varients.  I suspect Java knows whether the wait timed out or not but there is no way for the caller to figure it out without re-testing the condition and specifically testing the time.  Ugly.

So you will need to put the `wait(long timeout)` in a `while` loop as well and *also* test to see if the time is past the timeout period.  I know of no other way to accomplish this.

```
long timeoutExpiredMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeoutMs;
while (!condition) {
    long waitMillis = timeoutExpiredMs - System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (waitMillis <= 0) {
       // timeout expired
       break;
    }
    // we assume we are in a synchronized (object) here
    object.wait(waitMillis);
    // we might be improperly awoken here so we loop around to see if the
    // condition is still true or if we timed out
}
```

Comment: not sure it's a deficiency. suppose we know the exact reason for the wakeup, what can you do with it? we must recheck condition anyway.

Comment: If wait returned a boolean @irreputable then you wouldn't need to test for expiration at least.  You'd know whether you'd got notified or not.

Comment: even if wakeup is due to timeout, condition can still become true. since we desire the condition to be true here, we should recheck it regardless (checking is usually cheap).

Comment: @Gray definitely not a deficiency of Java. Google "spurious wakeup". Basically the fact that you got a wakeup means only that thread scheduler thinks that you should be woken up or it is making things easier for him on multicore system. But it does not necessarily mean that the condition has been met.

Comment: I certainly know about "spurious wakeup" @PavelZdenek.  The deficiency I was talking about was the inability of the `wait(timeout)` method to report back whether it timed out or not.  I suspect that it knows.  Btw, everyone talks about spurious wakeups but the real reason for the `while` loop is producer/consumer race conditions.  See here: http://256.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/

Comment: It knows perhaps only if it did the time comparison itself. `pthread_cond_timedwait` doesn't give that information either. So both APIs decided to leave the work to programmer :) Regarding your blog (nice domain grab btw), it all depends on what the scheduler exactly does when condition is signalled. I was working once with a thin crossplatform mutexing library which explicitly unlocked the mutex before signalling and the wakeups without reaching condition were still occuring (quite often), so i am a spurious believer since  :)

Comment: There's a catch in your code, object.wait(...) can throw IllegalArgumentException when the computed difference becomes negative. This can happen for example if a spurious timeout happens at timeoutExpiredMs - 5, the timeout check happens before timeoutExpiredMs, condition is false and until the next object.wait(...) gets executed, more than 5ms pass (e.g. another thread is scheduled)

Comment: how does timeoutMs get set?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @red888.  `timeoutMs` is the timeout value that you choose to wait for the lock.  If you want to wait 10seconds then set `timeoutMs` to 10000.

Answer (score 2):

```
long deadline = now() + timeout;

synchronized(lock)

    while( !condition() && now()<deadline )
        lock.wait( deadline - now() );

    if(condition())
        ...
    else // timeout
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

it is because java has Mesa style monitors instead of Hoare style monitors. So you need to put wait in a while loop.
Please search the string "For this reason, it is usually necessary to enclose each wait operation in a loop like this" on the follwing web page,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Nonblocking_condition_variables

.if it had been a Hoare style monitors then you could have put your wait in if. I will soon add details of  Mesa monitors. This is not deficiency in Java. Both types of monitors have advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Calling wait in a loop isn't just for handling the occasional spurious wakeup. In the general (non-toy example) case where multiple threads are contending for the lock, at the time a thread wakes up from wait any checks it made *prior to waiting* aren't enough to predict what state the object is in *after waiting*. The thread that was waiting had relinquished the lock so anything could have happened since then, and moreover there's nothing atomic about how notifications work, just because you got notified doesn't mean another thread didn't sneak in in the time between when the notification was made and the notified thread reacquired the lock.

Fundamentally you wait in a loop because once you have reacquired the lock you need to check the current state, in order to be able to tell what's going on. Having a timeout doesn't change that. A timeout is a safety mechanism so that if a notification is missed the thread won't hang forever. If the wait times out there usually isn't any specific action needed, just reacquire the lock, proceed to the loop body, and check the condition as usual.

And this isn't Java's fault, this is how pthreads work.